# Name for a type of idiom with two things joined (like "raining cats and dogs", "bread and butter")

Tags: expressions, idioms, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions, taxonomy

I had heard, a number of years ago, that there is a name for an type of idiomatic expression in which two things are joined to refer to one thing.

An example of this would be “raining *cats and dogs*”. This does not mean that *cats* is a metaphor for one type of rain, and *dogs* another, but rather that the combined terms form a joint expression with a single referent.

Likewise, “*bread and butter*” could be used similarly, e.g., “they should waste their time trying to sell frozen steaks; jewelry is QVC’s *bread and butter*”.

Is there a name for the specific type of idiomatic expression?

Comment: [“pros and cons”, “black and white”, “ups and downs”. Always in a fixed sequence, is there a word or phrase for these?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198465/pros-and-cons-black-and-white-ups-and-downs-always-in-a-fixed-sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the word for this is hendiadys: literally "one from two". The term is used when two things are joined together to refer to one.

Answer (score 5):

The generic term [collocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) includes idiomatically paired nouns, which both OP's examples are. So I'd say they are *collocated pairs*.

Other idiomatic usages such as *strong tea* and *powerful computers* are also collocations. In those cases, competent speakers recognise *powerful tea* and *strong computers* as "wrong", primarily because we're used to the other versions. Grammar and meaning aren't really relevant - it's just a matter of what people *happen to say*.

It's also worth noting that we never say it's *raining dogs and cats*. But as [this NGram shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cats%20and%20dogs,dogs%20and%20cats&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), we actually use that sequence more often than *cats and dogs* when we're not talking about the weather. Word sequence is one of the attributes of a collocation, though - *coach and horses* only occurs in that order.

Comment: That's a little nice explanation you've got there.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: I can't deny I already pontificated about noun-pair order back on [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32822/which-comes-first-cat-or-dog). It's fascinated me ever since I first noticed *nobody else was noticing* that my parents put my name first when refering to me and my wife, but my in-laws put her name first. But I know I haven't really answered OP's exact question - if there is indeed a special term for the *two nouns = one referent* concept, I just don't know it.

Comment: In the native language of the country I now live in, it's even better than that. If you, Fumble Fingers, were married to the irresistible Nimble Fingers, your family would refer to you at "the Fumbles" and hers would call you "the Nimbles".

Comment: Haha I'll be on the lookout for Nimble then, if she's as attractive as you say (and good at house/bedwork, as I'd like to hope the name implies). When I started using my handle back in the late 90s, my (now ex-) wife briefly used FumbleToes, but it never really worked... :)

Comment: I looked at your NGram data; it doesn't seem to show what you say. All it says is that "dogs and cats" is more frequently used. I don't see any support for the claim about context. I agree that it is intuitively true, but the data doesn't seem to me to offer any useful support either way.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: I don't follow you. You seem to agree D&C is slightly more common. Even more so if you only consider the last 50 years, though I agree the difference isn't that remarkable anyway. But some of those instances of C&D obviously actually do follow "raining", so if you ignore them the difference can only become more marked, surely?

Comment: ...and if proof were needed, [here's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raining+dogs+and+cats%2Craining+cats+and+dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) the evidence that *raining dogs and cats* simply doesn't occur enough to mention.

Comment: I wasn't saying your conclusion was wrong, only that your evidence didn't support the conclusion. What would be more supportive of your conclusion is this http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raining+cats+and+dogs%2Cdogs+and+cats&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 which shows D&C far more common than raining C&D, which is essentially your point.

Comment: @Fraser Orr: My core point in the answer was that "collocated pairs" normally have a specific order. In the case of *cats and dogs* or *dogs and cats*, these two often occur together, but not markedly in either sequence. **Except** in the idiomatic expression *raining cats and dogs*, which is always in that order. If my "evidence" didn't support any of those assertions, it was probably because I didn't think any of it was contentious. Or maybe because I was just careless. Anyway, I don't think we really disagree on anything substantive. :)

Comment: "bread and butter" and "cats and dogs" are examples of [*irreversible  binomials*, *binomial pairs*, *freezes*, and *Siamese twins*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249264/why-a-bow-and-arrow/249481#249481) It's much more than collocations. See also related question which I posted beneath the OP.