# What is the term that means "how a noun and verb match"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the word (I believe it starts with a "C") which means that a noun and a verb go together, e.g.: you can:

- hold a meeting
- start a meeting
- end a meeting

but it would be odd to say that you:

- make a meeting
- create a meeting
- do a meeting

etc.

I learned the word a long time ago in a linguistics class I took, it's something like "correlate" or "conjugate" but I can't remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is *[collocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation)*.

Comment: Or this. Something new every day!

Comment: awesome, I knew I was close with "co..." something, thanks!

Comment: The term *collocation* simply means any idiomatic usages where particular words are normally used together with no semantic or grammatical justification for not using other words. It's not specific to *verb+noun*, or [noun+noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45310/name-for-a-type-of-idiom-with-two-things-joined-like-raining-cats-and-dogs) pairings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be *complementary*, and [it's not just for nouns](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAComplement.htm).