# Is "from" superflous following "stop" or "prevent"?

Tags: prepositions, redundancy, negative-polarity-items

I seem to encounter this more from British speakers, but they'll often say something like

> Protect it from heat to prevent the contents expanding.

instead of

> Protect it from heat to prevent the contents from expanding.

It used to annoy me that *from* is omitted, but thinking about the meaning of the word, I'm not sure it makes sense to include it.  I suspect it has been carried over from the phrasing *to keep from happening*, being synonymous with *prevent*.  *From* makes sense to me here because *keep* is positional, and *from* signals where it shall not be.  Omitting *from* would make the meaning positive, such that we'd ensure some action continues.  But *prevent* and *stop* are already negative, and they're not positional.

In this related post, *prevent to happen* (which seems to me essentially the same as *prevent happening*) is compared to *prevent from happening*, but it seems only to address how common each is: ["Preventing them to wrap" vs "Preventing them from wrapping"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250406/preventing-them-to-wrap-vs-preventing-them-from-wrapping)

I know the inclusion of *from* is far more common; is it superfluous?  Further, is it even *logical* to include it?

Comment: The BrE/ArE is false. to + action verb + gerund is common in both.

Comment: It may be that the dropped "from" is actually traceable to a slightly different construction: "prevent the contents' exploding" versus "prevent the contents from exploding"—or in pronoun form,  "prevent their exploding" versus "prevent them from exploding." In the possessive construction, including "from" would be ungrammatical.

Comment: @Lambie sorry, I don't know what "The BrE/ArE is false" means, and my searches aren't turning up anything that seems relevant.  Could you expand on that?

Comment: I meant: BrE/AmE. British and American English.

Comment: The second U in superfluous isn't superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in fact, a case of variation between dialects. [In American English, as one can see from Ngram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prevent+him+getting%2Cprevent+him+from+getting%2Cprevent+his+getting&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) "prevent him from getting" is much more prevalent than "prevent him getting" or "prevent his getting."   [In British English,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prevent+him+getting%2Cprevent+him+from+getting%2Cprevent+his+getting&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) all three are common, though the version with "from" is still the most prevalent. To me (an AmE speaker), the version without "from" sounds very awkward, if not outright wrong.

Curiously, if you replace "getting" with "being," then the version with the genitive ("prevent his being") is [somewhat common in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prevent+him+being%2Cprevent+him+from+being), but the version with the accusative ("prevent him being") is still rare. This also agrees with my intuition; to me these sentences do sound more acceptable with a genitive subject.

Comment: I think it's because I've watched a lot of British programs but I'm starting to like the phrasing without "from". Although whenever I try to use it, the "from" just naturally comes out. It's too ingrained.

Answer (score 1):

> Protect it from heat to prevent the contents expanding.
>
> instead of
>
> Protect it from heat to prevent the contents from expanding.

In the first, expanding is a participle acting in its meaning of "doing the action of the verb to expand." Its subject is "the contents".

In the second, expanding is a gerund in its meaning of "the action of the verb to expand" which, when modified by the preposition **from** forms an adjunct (adverbial).

Both are perfectly acceptable in American and British English.

Comment: If it were a participle, the sentence would mean "Protect it from heat to prevent the contents, which are expanding," no?

Comment: Not as I see it. There is a chance that the contents will expand and there needs to be something that will prevent the contents "*doing the action of the verb to expand*" -> it is expanding = it is doing the action of the verb to expand.