# Name for the practice of composing sentences for ease and clarity of pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, poetry

Is there a name for the practice of composing sentences in such a way that they don't contain proximate consonants which cause difficulty when read aloud?

For example: Under this criteria, ***"dogs and cats"*** is preferable to ***"cats and dogs,"*** because the consecutive ***d*** s in the latter are difficult to pronounce clearly and distinctly and will force the speaker to either interrupt the flow of speech or elide the first ***d***.

Comment: I think your rational re the [*Which comes first: cat or dog?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32822/) is pretty much 100% spurious. People tend to repeat the sequence they hear most often, but they normally take note of *context*. In fact, there's [no significant overall preference](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/32837/2637) re the sequence ***cats*** and ***dogs***. But idiomatically you'll probably *never* hear anyone say *"It's raining dogs and cats"*, so you won't say that yourself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok. And my question is: what is the name for this "rationale" which you think is "spurious"?

Comment: This term is close, but not quite what I'm looking for: [phonotactic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics).

Comment: But ... in ordinary speech, nobody pronounces the "d" in "and" in ***either*** "cats and dogs" or "dogs and cats".

Comment: "Obsessive compulsive", maybe.

Comment: I think I'd be more likely to stumble over "dogs and cats" than "cats and dogs".

Answer (score 1):

You're close with "phonotactic".  But you would have to use phonotactic argot to devise some descriptive phrase for varying the adjacent "coda" and "onset" consonants.

Comment: +1 Yes Brian, exactly. This is not an answer, but you're the only one so far who understands the question.