# Why is it "ladies and gentlemen" instead of "gentlemen and ladies"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, word-order, collocation, list-order

Why is it "ladies and gentlemen" instead of "gentlemen and ladies"?

Is there a specific reason for this? After all, it is "boys and girls", rather than "girls and boys". If the boy (male) comes first here, why doesn't it come first in "ladies and gentlemen"?

Comment: Because it's "ladies first".

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198465/pros-and-cons-black-and-white-ups-and-downs-always-in-a-fixed-sequence/198474#198474

Comment: There are some questions on EL&U about siamese twins and binomials in English. Related: [Reversing Binomials](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298098/reversing-binomials), and [Is “forth and back” more proper than “back and forth”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76999/is-forth-and-back-more-proper-than-back-and-forth) and [Why “a” bow and arrow?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249264/why-a-bow-and-arrow)

Comment: also related: [Why do we say kith & kin and not kin & kith?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246512/why-do-we-say-kith-kin-and-not-kin-kith) and [“Mom and Dad” vs “Dad and Mom”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121756/mom-and-dad-vs-dad-and-mom)

Comment: It's not universally "boys and girls" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boys+and+girls%2C+girls+and+boys&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) has 4:1 "b&G":"g&b" in 2000, peak of 16:1 in the 30s).  The pattern is [rather different](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ladies+and+gentlemen%2Cgentlemen+and+ladies&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) for "ladies and gentlemen": diverging rather than converging.

Comment: @HotLicks except "Lords and ladies" is the other way around.

Comment: @abligh - But clearly lords are more important than ladies.

Comment: (Besides, the *correct* address is "Good evening, ladies and germs.")

Comment: Maybe they just copied "Meine Damen und Herren" or "Mesdames et Messieurs"...

Comment: @ChrisH If you pull it back to 1750, it looks like there was a switch: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ladies+and+gentlemen%2Cgentlemen+and+ladies&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cladies%20and%20gentlemen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgentlemen%20and%20ladies%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @called2voyage: Also interesting is the [Ngram you get](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ladies+and+gentlemen%2Cgentlemen+and+ladies%2C+men+and+women%2C+women+and+men&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cladies%20and%20gentlemen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgentlemen%20and%20ladies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20and%20women%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20and%20men%3B%2Cc0) when you add "men and women" and "women and men" to the one you set up for "l&g" versus "g&l".

Comment: It's all to do with Ablaut Reduplication...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It probably has to do with the phonetic and metrical properties of "ladies and gentlemen" versus "gentlemen and ladies." Say them both out loud and see which one sounds better to you, intuitively.

The metrical pattern of "ladies and gentlemen" consists of (arguably) two dactyls. A ***dactyl*** is a group of three syllables where the first is stressed and the second two are unstressed. When these occur in succession, they are pleasant to the ear.

- **la**dies and **gent**lemen
- **DUM** da da / **DUM** da da

The metrical pattern of "gentlemen and ladies" falls into a much less regular pattern. It is less pleasant to the ear. It is something like a stressed syllable followed by three unstressed syllables followed by a stressed syllable followed by an unstressed syllable.

- **gent**lemen and **la**dies
- **DUM** da da da **DUM** da

Our language tends to organize itself according to regular and pleasant stress patterns. My guess is that is why we feel more drawn to "ladies and gentlemen" than "gentlemen and ladies" and why the former has conventionalized.

Comment: I think politeness and order of deference is a more likely explanation. It is normally "my lords, ladies and gentlemen"

Comment: [Women and children first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_and_children_first) and [Ladies First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladies_First)

Comment: If it's order of deference, why not "girls and boys" instead of "boys and girls" then?

Comment: @Gnubie: In that example it could still be argued that the this deference doesn't extent to children, 'lords and ladies' thus seems a more reasonable counter example (albeit less common).

Comment: I  agree with those who have said so that deference and the "ladies first" convention might also have something to do with it, especially considering that it's an address (unlike "boys and girls"). There are probably *multiple* factors which contributed to "ladies and gentlemen" becoming a set phrase.

Comment: @DavidMulder Also, '**lords** and **la**dies' balances the stressed / unstressed syllables much better than the alternative. It seems like the perfect counter example.

Comment: "Our language tends to organize itself according to regular and pleasant stress patterns." Is there a citation for this? Also, is it true for other languages?

Answer (score 14):

It comes from "***My Lords, Ladies and Gentlemen***".  Titled men come first (My Lords); then their spouses [My] Ladies; Ladies also include non-titled ladies; and finally, untitled men (Gentlemen).  [Debretts, Preamble Precedents](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/hierarchies/official-functions/preamble-precedence)

> The following list gives the form in which important guests should be
>   included in a preamble in order of precedence:
>
> Your Royal Highness
>
> My Lord Mayor (My Lord Provost, etc) See (i)
>
> Mr Recorder (outside London)
>
> Mr Chairman of the ...... County Council (outside Greater London)
>
> My Lord Chancellor
>
> Prime Minister (or, more formally, Mr. Prime Minister). See (ii)
>
> Your Excellency (ies) (this refers to Ambassadors and High
>   Commissioners)
>
> Your Grace(s). See (iii)
>
> My Lord(s). See (iv)
>
> Ladies and Gentlemen. See (v)

If you want to know what the footnotes (i) through (v) say, so you will be absolutely correct at your next speech, click on the link.

Answer (score 8):

Ladies first. To quote something I had drilled into me from childhood: when serving,

- visiting ladies
- home ladies
- visiting gentlemen
- home gentlemen
- yourself.

Comment: Speculation doesn't hold up to scrutiny. Something specific about the words "ladies" and "gentlemen" other than gender politics leads to that word order. Consider, for example, ["men and women of color" is slightly more common than "women and men of color"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=men+and+women+of+color%2Cwomen+and+men+of+color&year_start=1980), whereas ["ladies and gentlemen" is vastly more common than "gentlemen and ladies"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ladies+and+gentlemen%2Cgentlemen+and+ladies&year_start=1980).

Comment: @200_success Do you have some evidence? I have never heard the the phrase 'men and women of color' in my life, or the reverse. Who exactly is speculating here?

Comment: Those links _were_ the evidence. (The phrase is probably more of an Americanism, so it might be unusual to you.) Anyway, you could do the same search with "men and women" vs. "women and men" and arrive at the same findings.