# Why does "north" come before "south", and "black" before "white"?

Tags: writing-style, coordinating-conjunctions, list-order, freezes

> This website is common in both **north** and **south** America.

Or is this better?

> This website is common in both **south** and **north** America.

Let's ask Google:

- ["in north and south"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22in+north+and+south%22): 26,800,00 hits
- ["in south and north"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22in+south+and+north%22): 592,000 hits

Why there is a huge difference?

There are too many other examples, such as *white* and *black,* *high* and *low,* etc.

---

In an academic/professional writing context, if there is no logical reason for any order, should one just preserve the common order? Does using the uncommon order look strange?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but it would be hard to find the original. Look for "binomials" and "fixed" and "order".

Comment: You're right: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298098/reversing-binomials

Comment: Time to look at [Cooper and Ross](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/130851/15299) again.

Comment: A rather daunting read @JohnLawler!  Do they suggest that there is a 'pecking order' for which parameter is dominant?  And do they find that different languages behave similarly?  I have always been intrigued by the fact that English says '***black and white***' whereas Spanish says '***blanco y negro***'.

Comment: @Dan - I think you answered your own question.  Note that the percussive "black" and "blanco" come first.  I think you can find a similar pattern with most of the others.  Certain orders "roll off the tongue" more readily than others.

Comment: Hmm ... black and white, black and blue, red and black....  I think I'm going to have to read Cooper and Ross.